# How to disable automatic dns server route creation with DHCP on amazon aws ubuntu ec2

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I need my AWS systems to resolve DNS through my on-premise DNS server.

I have a wireguard VPN between my onprem network (172.19.0.0/24) and an instance on my AWS network (172.16.0.0/23).

I set the DHCP options on AWS to use my on-premise DNS server - 172.19.0.15.

I set my VPC to route all traffic to 172.19.0.0/24 to my wireguard server (172.16.0.163).

When the wireguard server renews its lease it's pulling the right DNS server but also adding a static route for 172.19.0.15 back to the default gateway.

This creates a route loop and dns fails for the whole network (since everyone is using 172.19.0.15 now).

```
ubuntu@ip-172-16-0-163:~$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
100.10.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wg0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
172.16.0.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wg0
172.19.0.15     172.16.0.1      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
```

This fixes things but is temporary:

`sudo route delete 172.19.0.15 gateway 172.16.0.1`

I figure there are two ways I can solve this.
1 - configure networking to not rely on DHCP.
2 - add the route delete command somewhere on the network startup or somewhere after DHCP runs.
3 - fix the root problem and stop the system from creating the route in the first place

All three of these are beyond my sys adm

Comment: Probably the same issue as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410196/dhcp-provided-dns-server-with-wrong-route-in-ubuntu-server-22-04

Comment: This is it. I ended up reading up on netplan and systemd.network to discover how to set RoutesToDNS to false. I didn't know about drop-ins so I simply copied netplan's config file, changed it from 10. to 5. and set RoutesToDNS=false. Your linked answer is better.